# Change details on Backbone.JS collection change event

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

Is there a way to gather more information about the changes from within the Backbone.JS collection change event. What I would like to figure out is whether or not it possible to to know what the collection change was; was a model updated, was one added or removed from the collection and also, for every of these, figure out which one.

Answer (score 0):

Different events 
When model is added to collection

```
collection.on('add',this.someFunc,this);
```

When a model is removed from a collection.

```
collection.on('remove',this.someFunc,this);
```

There is no change event on collection but you need to listen on models change event for change

in model:

```
initialize:function(){
  this.on('change',function(){
  this.collection.trigger('change');
});
}
```

Now on collection you can hear for change event

```
collection.on('change',this.someFunc,this);
```

refer [this](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) for list of all backbone built-in events